# Changing the selected option with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to change the selected option with jQuery.

```
<select name="nameSelect" id="idSelect">
    <option value="0">Text0</option>
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>TextSelected1</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying with `$("#idSelect").val();` or similar, but it doesn't work.

Regards

Comment: To set value `.val('whatever')` and to get `.val()` is enough.

Comment: $("#idSelect").val("0"); works

Comment: you can use something like this. $("#idSelect").val("1");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does work, but you need to include the value of the option you want selected as a parameter to `val()`, e.g.:

```
$("#idSelect").val('1');
```

Answer (score 2):

pass the value which needs to be set as parameter in `.val()` :

```
$("#idSelect").val('0');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the value in the val as

```
$("#idSelect").val(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the value of the select. And I would suggest it to use the `select[name=NAME]`-Tag..

`$('select[name=nameSelect]').val(1);`

Greetings from Vienna

Comment: Why would you suggest selecting by `name` instead of `id`? It is slower (significantly, in some cases); if `id` is a possibility then surely use it...

Comment: Because the code will be more clearer - and you do not need to set an ID. When you make bigger forms which are complicated this is easier and thats why I prefer it. I don't think that it is slower and this wouldn't be noticed!